# How to fix ThreadStateException() in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have an application that runs a thread to play one or more songs. To create playlists, I update the information every second grid. After creating a playlist, if the thread is not started and the playlist is greater than 0, I run a thread to play songs.
  This is the scan I do:

```
if(!thrPlayMusic.IsAlive && existData)
                thrPlayMusic.Start();
```

However, on some occasions, the system is generating the exception ThreadStateException (), saying that the thread is already started. But how can he throw this exception, and check if the thread is active and then start its processing? can someone help me? Thank you!

Comment: You should lock the if

Comment: I do not understand what you said...

Comment: c# lock reference -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/c5kehkcz.aspx most likely the thread starts after you check but before you issue the start statement

Comment: Which thread are you creating the playlists on? Which thread is running the code you posted?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement some kind of `lock` element.  This will prevent multiple threads from accessing a piece of code and prevents race conditions like the one you describe.

Rework your code to something like

```
private static object lockObject = new lockObject();
```

With the above lock

```
lock(lockObject)
{
   if(!thrPlayMusic.IsAlive && existData)
       thrPlayMusic.Start();
}
```

This will ensure only one thread is in the lock block; any other threads coming in will wait on the lock statement until the current thread is done.

Note: The above will not work well if the `thrPlayMusic.Start();` method takes a long time to return.

Comment: Plz don't recommend him to use `lock` over a thread. He should create an object.

Comment: @SAM I do not quite follow. There are multiple threads starting the player. Can you explain how creating an object resolve the issue?

Comment: I mean create an object an do lock that object rather than lock the thread itself. It may cause a deadlock.

Comment: @SAM you are right, I did not give due attention to the object I was locking on. Have corrected it.